# Oracle Ref cursor along with out parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, ref-cursor

I have a requirement to have a IN OUT parameter along with a reference cursor as a return from a stored procedure. Currently I am doing following.

```
create table dept
( dept_id number,
  name varchar2(40),
  location varchar2(200)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE HR.SP_PACKAGE AS 

  TYPE dept_type IS REF CURSOR RETURN HR.dept%ROWTYPE;

END SP_PACKAGE;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HR.MIXED_IN_INOUT_REF_PARAM 
(
  P_ID IN NUMBER  
, P_NAME_TO_LOCATION IN OUT VARCHAR2  
, P_RCURSOR OUT SP_PACKAGE.dept_type
) AS 
BEGIN
  SELECT name INTO P_NAME_TO_LOCATION FROM HR.dept WHERE dept_id = p_id AND name =  P_NAME_TO_LOCATION;
  OPEN P_RCURSOR FOR
      select *
      from HR.dept;
END MIXED_IN_INOUT_REF_PARAM;
```

I am getting hit with some errors at run time even though the compilation is successful.

```
ORA-06550: line 4, column 17:
PLS-00201: identifier 'CURSOR' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 4, column 13:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 12, column 18:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 9, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 21, column 17:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 21, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I am using Sql Developer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you sure they are all created and compiled please reconfirm

Comment: there was a small issue in package definition. Got around it by removing the database qualifier (e.g: CREATE OF REPLACE PACKAGE SP_PACKAGE AS ..). Now they both compile and package and procedure is shown as created.

Comment: Please edit your post and include the code which issues the call to the PL/SQL procedure.  Thanks.

Comment: the synonym might be the reason please check

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you didn't prefix `dept` in the `create table` script with `HR`. If you're running this script from another schema/login, then none of your other objects can see that table.

Comment: Please show the failing code, which refers to something called `CURSOR` at line 4 column 17. The code as posted (without the `HR.` prefix as I don't have an HR user to test with) is fine.

Answer (score 0):

change like this
remove the return

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE HR.SP_PACKAGE AS 

  TYPE dept_type IS REF CURSOR ;

END SP_PACKAGE;
```

you can make it more dynamic thought like this

```
open p_cursor FOR  'SELECT *  FROM DEPT where ' ||  V_WHERE;
```

Comment: I tried removing the return with no luck. :(. On your second suggestion would it help me to solve the above particular issue? I am not sure I got that entirely. Bit confused about V_WHERE parameter. Sorry if these are trivial issues. Just starting out with Oracle. :).

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your proc `chamibuddhika` ,i think there is some problem with how you called it .I tried creating the same procedure and it works fine .try to run you procedure as shown below:

```
declare
v_temp varchar2(200):='ACCOUNTING';
rec SP_PACKAGE.dept_type;
v_rec rec%ROWTYPE;

begin
MIXED_IN_INOUT_REF_PARAM(10,v_temp,rec);

LOOP
FETCH rec INTO v_rec;
EXIT WHEN rec%NOTFOUND;
 dbms_output.put_line(v_rec.name);

END LOOP;

end;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 ACCOUNTING
 RESEARCH
 SALES
 OPERATIONS
```

There is one issue with your proc ,when the query inside proc does not return anything ,it will give you `no_data_found` exception.So you need to handle that in your proc.